# Confusion about the $ operator and parentheses

Tags: haskell

I'm working my way through the first haskell book and struggle with the `$` operator:

The following line works:

```
map (>= 16) . take 5 $ iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2
```

However, the following doesn't:

```
map (>= 16) . take 5 (iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2)
```

> Possible cause: `take' is applied to too many arguments

I don't see the problem here. `take` takes an int and a list. To my understanding, I provided both arguments.

What do I have to do if I want to avoid the `$` operator?

Comment: The original is equivalent to `(map (>= 16) . take 5) (iterate (\x -> x^2) 2)`. `.` expects its operands to be functions. You could also write `map (>= 16) $ take 5 (iterate (\x -> x^2) 2)`.

Comment: `map (>= 16) . take 5 (iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2)` actually means `(map (>= 16)) . (take 5 (iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2))` so `(.)` is passed a function and a list instead of two functions. Remember that application `f x y z` has higher priority over any infix like `+` or `.`.

Comment: I often follow the rule: separate functions by `.` and the argument by `$` This would give `map (>=16) . take 5 . iterate (^2) $ 2`

Comment: You need to pay careful attention to currying and partial application. `take` is not a function of two arguments; it is a function of one argument that returns another function. Adding some redundant parentheses,  `(map (>= 16)) . take` does not type check, but `(map (>= 16)) . (take 5)` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) operator is a function that simply has a **the lowest priority** (`infixr 0`, only [`($!)` and `seq` have the same priority](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-820004.4.2)). As a result:

```
map (>= 16) . take 5 $ iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(map (>= 16) . take 5) (iterate  (\x -> x^2) 2)
```

so also with brackets for the left operand as well.

It is actually a nice thing about Haskell that you can use operators as a grouping mechanism: `($)` is simply defined as `($) f x = f x`, but because of the fact that it is an operator, it can be used as a way to avoid brackets.